# Official version of Toast.show() method gives me a error

Tags: toast

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY3Kx.jpg)
Just trying a simple toast message for my app and copy paste the code from the developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#kotlin
yet get an error. Why is the toast.show() line not allowed?

I searched everywhere and can't find an answer.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but it's inside another method that is expecting a `Boolean` return value.

Try adding at the bottom of your method `return true` or the desired return `Boolean` value. Or you can convert your method to a `Unit` method.

```
fun myMethod() {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Hi" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    toast.show()
}
```